# How to get only IP address

Tags: powershell

I have this kind of script in powershell

```
$NW = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
$IP= " IPAddress: " + $NW.IPAddress
```

How do i get only IP addres and not that trash next to it?
Result is at the moment IPaadress:  xxxxxx fe80::9480:1f5c:9c1f:d03d

Comment: That "trash" are other (virtual) IP (v6) addresses...

Comment: Ok! How do i get IPv4Addres only then by this kind of command.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ipAddressV4List = (Get-WmiObject  -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration).Where{$_.IPAddress}.foreach{$_.IPAddress[0]}
$ipAddressV4List
```

```
192.168.1.7
10.235.3.220
```

```
(Get-NetIPAddress | Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq 'IPv4'}).IPAddress
```

```
(Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration).Where{$_.IPAddress}.foreach{$_.IPAddress[0]}
```

Comment: Prefer the last solution (`Get-NetIpAddress ...`). If you absolutly want to use the `Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` class, then prefer a CIM call with `Get-CimInstance` instead (but, for both, you need at least Windows 8.0 / Server 2012).

Comment: which makes sense